# Сортировка по связанному полю

Tags: python, django

Как можно отсортировать результат выборки по полю связанному модели?

У меня есть выборка:

```
qs = Dialogs.objects.all()
```

В результате я получаю 10 существующих записей. К каждому диалогу есть много сообщений. И я хочу отсортировать диалоги по дате последнего сообщения в каждом из них.

Первое что пришло в голову:

```
qs = qs.order_by('messages__Time')
```

Но в итоге получаю итератор, содержащий повторяющиеся диалоги столько раз, сколько сообщений в каждом из них! То есть, например, в диалоге с id=31 содержится 20 сообщений. И вот в этом qs я получаю 20 диалогов с id=31 (отсортированных :)) ). Как это сделать правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Объединения и агрегатные функции](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/#joins-and-aggregates) помогут:

```
qs = (Dialogs.objects
             .annotate(newest_message=Max('messages__Time'))
             .order_by('newest_message'))
```

Comment: Точно. Спасибо!